# Has the chere package been removed from Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I just tried installing chere, but it doesn't appear to be available. It doesn't show up in the available packages during install and I can't install it using `apt-cyg` either:

```
$ apt-cyg install chere

...

Installing chere
Package chere not found or ambiguous name, exiting
```

So, I ran a `cygcheck`:

```
$ cygcheck -c chere
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status

$
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: http://cygwin.com/packages/

Answer (score 1):

It seems not to be available in the 64bit version.

The 32 bit edition lets you install Chere just fine.